# Python/HTML Integration Error

Tags: python, html

I am receiving this error when trying to use Python Server Pages with Mod_Python in Apache:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229, in _process_target
result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128, in _execute_target
result = object(arg)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/psp.py", line 336, in handler
p = PSP(req)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/psp.py", line 119, in __init__
self.load_from_file()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/psp.py", line 191, in load_from_file
code = compile(source, filename, "exec")

  File "/var/www/inventory/index.psp", line 3

    <% from __future__ import print_function

SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

Comment: mod_python is deprecated, use mod_wsgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your index.psp file either has a `__future__` import that isn't at the top of the file, or (more likely imo) the file that is including your index.psp for processing is doing a bunch of work before the `__future__` import is hit causing the error.

Comment: I believe this to be the case - I just removed the from __future__ imports

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

I don't think that you have to import the `print_function` to do statements like this

```
print("somthing")
```

Did you try it without this import?